# dynamic Linq contains from a string

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Working on a dynamic filtering system where the UI sends in the fields and the list of values in which to return:

```
IQueryable FilterByUi(IQueryable query, string fieldName, List<Object> values)
{
    string whereClause = BuildWhereClause( filedName, values);
    query.Where(whereClause)
    return query;
}

string BuildWhereClause(string fieldName, List<Object> values)
{
    List<string> valuesList = values.Select( value => $"x.{fieldName} == {value}").ToList();
    return $"x => {string.Join( " || ",  valuesList )}";
}
```

Example input would be for FieldName = "PropFromUi" and the list of Values is (440, 1126, 661).

Right now the BuildWhereClause will return a string that looks like this:

`"x => x.PropFromUi == 440 || x.PropFromUi == 1126 || x.PropFromUi == 661"`

I am wondering if there is a way to use a Contains rather than a list of OR statements, but keep it all in a string.

Comment: `(440, 1126, 661).Contains(x)`

Comment: Are you using Dynamic LINQ to support a string based `Where`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Does `ValueTuple` support `Contains`?

Comment: do you use dynamic-linq same as this https://gist.github.com/afreeland/6733381 or https://code-maze.com/using-dynamic-linq/

Comment: @RobertHarvey Maybe an array instead of `ValueTuple`, it doesn't implement `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`

Comment: @NetMage Yes he does. Said in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do not use Dynamic LINQ in such case. Simple Expression Tree composing makes more flexible function for this task.

```cs
var query = ctx.Products
   .FilterByValues("Category.CategoryId", new object[] { "1", 2 });
```

And implementation:

```cs
public static class QueryableDynamicExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> FilterByValues<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propPath, IEnumerable<object> values)
    {
        var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
        var propExpression = MakePropPath(entityParam, propPath.Split('.'));
        var itemType = propExpression.Type;

        // apply conversion
        // ConvertItems(values)
        var itemsExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(QueryableDynamicExtensions), nameof(ConvertItems),
            new[] { itemType }, Expression.Constant(values));

        // ConvertItems(values).Contains(e.SomeProp)
        var filterBody = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Contains), new[] { itemType },
            itemsExpression, propExpression);

        // e => ConvertItems(values).Contains(e.SomeProp)
        var filterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(filterBody, entityParam);

        return source.Where(filterLambda);
    }

    static Expression MakePropPath(Expression objExpression, string[] path)
    {
        return path.Aggregate(objExpression, Expression.PropertyOrField);
    }

    static IEnumerable<TItem> ConvertItems<TItem>(IEnumerable<object> items)
    {
        return items.Select(i => (TItem)Convert.ChangeType(i, typeof(TItem)));
    }       
}
```